# How do I convert date to plot it in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot simple weather data in R. I don't know how do I convert the following datetime. Please help.

```
> datetime
 [1] "2022-01-18" "2022-01-19" "2022-01-20" "2022-01-21" "2022-01-22"
 [6] "2022-01-23" "2022-01-24" "2022-01-25" "2022-01-26" "2022-01-27"
 [11] "2022-01-28" "2022-01-29" "2022-01-30" "2022-01-31" "2022-02-01"

> plot(datetime, temp)
 Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
 2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
 3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: What do you see after running this ? `class(datetime)` . If it returns character,  convert it to date by  `datetime <- as.Date(datetime,"%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: @maydin It did return character. I actually saw the docs and tried to do it earlier but I used lowercase y for year. It worked now. Thanks for the help.